# How do I play the sound of an mp3 file downloaded from the server - I am new to using streamed data

Tags: javascript, audio, playback

I have a file called test.mp3 on my server - I can play it

I am trying to download it using xmlhttprequest get and then assigning the response to an audio player.

I have tried

```
servpl.onclick = e =>{
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'sounds/test.mp3');

// Send the request over the network
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = function() {
if (xhr.status != 200) { // analyze HTTP status of the response
    alert(`Error ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`); // e.g. 404: Not Found
} else { // show the result
    alert(`Done, got ${xhr.response.length} bytes`); // response is the server response
    //    recordedAudio.autoplay=true;
    recordedAudio.src=xhr.response;
    recordedAudio.play();

   document.getElementById("display").innerHTML+=" after play sound";  
 
    }
};
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML+=" Server Play clicked";
```

}

Comment: You have tried the code example, what was the result? what is your question? Also your code appears to be badly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play that mp3 file using `audio` tag like so

```
<audio autoplay>
  <source src="sounds/test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

You can also create an `audio` tag using JS

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
audio.src = 'sounds/test.mp3';
audio.type = 'audio/mpeg';
document.body.appendChild(audio);
```

In this case, you will need to monitor `readyState` to see if the audio is loaded and ready to play. Another option is to add a handler for `oncanplay` event. Once audio is loaded you can execute `audio.play();` to start playing it.

Note that the major browsers will allow you to execute `audio.play()` command only from within `button.click` handler or other event handler triggered by a user.
This is a security measure to prevent websites from playing media automatically in the background without allowing users to see/control them.

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Working using the oncanplay event handler - MANY thanks

Comment: My apologies for not having done so - this is my first use of the system. I have been programming more than fifty years but I this is the first time I have dealt with streaming and using events triggered by 'long' duration statements - are you aware of any book or web-site that explains it all ?

Comment: No worries! Thanks! I used the `audio` tag for the first time somewhere around 2011. My general understanding of it comes from that time. I'm usually using [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio), or sometimes I may use [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp#:~:text=The%20tag%20is%20used,the%20first%20source%20it%20supports.) for quick cheatsheets. Hope this helps!